# Destructive measurement surface code: parity interpretation

Tags: surface-code, stabilizer-state

In the surface code the logical $Z_L$ operator is measured destructively at the end with the following procedure:

1. Measure all data qubits in the $Z$ basis with outcome $D_i \in \{\pm 1\}$
2. Compute error syndromes for $Z$-type plaquettes classically (given the measurement outcome)
3. Perform a decoding round and apply $X$ corrections where necessary (by flipping the classical measurement bit), resulting in $\hat{D}_i$.

Finally, the logical parity is determined by computing $\prod_i \hat{D}_i$. If it is $+1$ we measured $|0\rangle_L$, otherwise $|1\rangle_L$.

**Question:** I want to check my intuition on computing the product of the measurement outcomes:

Intuitively, we simply need to verify if an odd number of $X_L$ chains connected the corresponding boundaries.

For odd distance $d$, a logical $X_L$ error occurs if an odd number of $X_L$ operators are applied to the surface code. This implies, that an odd number of $X$ errors occurred (the logical chains cannot cross), and therefore an odd number of $-1$ is multiplied, yielding $-1$.

Is this the argument or is there something I missed?